# What is the difference between Receipt URL and Relay Response URL

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am using authorize.net SIM integration. In settings -> Response/Receipt URLs I saw two options Receipt URL and Relay Response URL. Could you please advise what is the difference between these two and for what purpose these two have to be set?

Answer (score 5):

**Relay Response** is a feature available to merchants using [Server Integration Method (SIM)](http://developer.authorize.net/api/sim/) or [Simple Checkout](http://developer.authorize.net/api/simplecheckout/). It instructs the payment gateway to return transaction results to the merchant using an HTML form POST to a specified URL on the merchant's Web server. A script or program at the URL can be used to create a custom receipt page using the transaction information. The custom receipt page is then relayed back to the customer's browser. Relay Response does not redirect the end user back to the merchant’s server, but relays the page content to the end user instead of displaying the Authorize.Net default receipt page. ([More from Authorize.Net](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Relay-Response-Basics-and-Troubleshooting/ba-p/9536))

A **Receipt Page** is static and does not receive POST data from Authorize.Net. If you do not need to offer customized information or wish to perform any database actions for the transaction then this is the option you would choose.